# Is there a way to dynamically scale a watermark?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, watermark, xwatermark

I've done quite a bit of research of trying to scale a watermark based on the text given. The issue is that if I enter a longer string, the text runs off the page.

I've tried various packages including: xwatermark, draftcopy, draftwatermark.

All of these packages don't seem to have an easy way to dynamically scale based on the text specified. The idea I have is to save the text into a box, and write a conditional statement to rescale or "squash" the box if the length runs off the page. This poses a challange as I want my watermark to be at a 45 degree angle.

Does anyone have a solution?

Here is some example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}%
\newsavebox\watermarkbox%
\savebox\watermarkbox{\tikz[color=red, opacity=0.3]\node[rotate=45,scale=15] at (current page.center) {This is a longer watermark.};}%
\newwatermark*[allpages]{\usebox\watermarkbox}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%
\title{Title of Document}
\author{Name of Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Please provide us with a complete MWE that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and can be compiled.

Comment: Thanks! The question has been updated. @marmot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adjustbox` comes with such a functionality.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}%
\usepackage{adjustbox}%
\newsavebox\watermarkbox%
\savebox\watermarkbox{\tikz[color=red, opacity=0.3]\node[rotate=45,scale=15] at (current page.center) {This is a longer watermark.};}%
\newwatermark*[allpages]{\maxsizebox{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}{\usebox\watermarkbox}}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%
\title{Title of Document}
\author{Name of Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm. Thank you.